Omni Data Mapper LOAD is creating a redundant child record
My question is similar to this. We have an existing Data Mapper (Data Raptor) which creates the Case record, and it's related records if they're present.
It's creating a blank child record only for this particular Object even the incoming JSON didn't have the child node for it.
Interestingly it's only happening to this object, similar other M-D child objects are not created.

Below M-D Object which is correctly omitted from the Data mapper.

Previewed Data mapper below with JSON input and created redundant record below,

Any workarounds to overcome this? other than creating a redundant flow to delete this extra record.
Thanks!

Will it be possible to also provide a screenshot of the other objects' mapping where it doesn't create an empty record?  For example the Radiology_Imaging_Required__c object

Thanks @AdriaanVanNiekerk, Added a screenshot of working object mapping above.

I think linking the related record like this is not a good idea, especially if there might be scenarios when no Case_Participant is provided.
When any if/then logic is necessary, I would suggest moving from just a Data Mapper to an Integration Procedure with multiple Data Mappers.
For your situation:

Create an Integration Procedure that receives the JSON
Have a Data Mapper create just the Case record (and the other records that seem to not be creating empty records)
Add a Conditional Block to check if Case_Participant info has been provided

If provided, use the returned caseId from the first Data Mapper with the other Case_Participant info in the JSON to create a record
If not, skip creating a Case_Participant record



While this is a bit more involved, it is a better route than creating a flow just to delete the record :-)
Good luck!
